# How to check if a month and year lies between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, sql-date-functions

I have a 2 columns in a table `startdate` and `enddate` and I need to create a function get all `ID` which lies between the date data passed in function.
my function input parameters are

```
@Year int,
@Month int = null,
@Quarter int = null
```

now if month is `null` I need to check only with date which is easy but if month is provided how to check if it lies between `startdate` and `enddate` or else if `@Quarter` is provided  I need to check if 3 months of the year collides with `startdate` and `enddate` .

What I have written upto now is

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAssociatesEmpID(
    @Year int,
    @Month int = null,
    @Quarter int = null
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS BEGIN
IF @Month IS NOT NULL -- Monthly Statistics
    BEGIN

    END
ELSE IF @Quarter IS NOT NULL -- Quarterly Statistics
    BEGIN

    END
ELSE -- Yearly Statistics
    BEGIN
        return SELECT ID FROM Table WHRER @Year>=YEAR(startdate) AND @Year<=YEAR(enddate)
    END
END
```

Kindly help me with condition with month and Quarter

Quarter has 4 possible inuts range between 1-4
and its month range is between `@Quarter*3-3` and `@Quarter*3`

Comment: `YEAR(@Year)` doesn't make any sense, `@Year` is already an `INT`

Comment: @Lamak oh mybad thanks for pointing

Comment: Is January 2016 between 2016-01-30 and 2016-02-02?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' yes it is

Comment: It looks like you simply want to check if two intervals overlap. First interval is between `startdate` and `enddate`. Second interval is defined by the parameters of the procedure. Convert your `@Year`, `@Month`, `@Quarter` parameters into two proper dates using several `IFs` and then check for overlapping.

Comment: Why not pass in a date datatype instead of splitting this into all these extra variables? And then you could make this sargable instead of wrapping your columns in date functions which prevents any index usage.

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating two local DateTime variables.  (Or DateTime2, or whatever data type your table's start and end date columns are using.)  Maybe call them @WhereStartDate and @WhereEndDate.

Use some IF statements to populate your new @WherexxxDate variables.  For example, if Month is provided, something like:

```
DECLARE @Year int = 2016;
DECLARE @Month int = 3;
DECLARE @WhereStartDate datetime;
DECLARE @WhereEndDate datetime;

SET @WhereStartDate = CONVERT( datetime, CAST(@Year as char(4)) + '/' + CAST(@Month as varchar(2)) + '/01');
SET @WhereEndDate = DATEADD( day, -1, DATEADD( month, 1, @WhereStartDate ));

SELECT @WhereStartDate, @WhereEndDate;
```

Once you have actual date/time variables, you can write your query appropriately...

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE startDate >= @WhereStartDate
AND   enddate <= @WhereEndDate
```

This has the added benefit of being sargable.  The way that you have written your query is non-sargable.  (In short, non-sargable queries will not make use of indexes properly and will have poor performance.  If the table is large, the resulting table scans could take a very long time.)

Answer (score 0):

Not where I can test, but this should be close...

```
WHERE 
    (@Year >= YEAR(startdate)) 
    AND 
    (@Year <= YEAR(startdate)) 
    AND 
    (
        ( (@Month IS NOT NULL) AND (@Month >= MONTH(startdate)) AND (@Month <= MONTH(startdate)) )
        OR 
        ( (@Month IS NULL) AND (@Quarter >= DATEPART(QUARTER, startdate)) AND (@Quarter <= DATEPART(QUARTER, startdate)) )
    )
```